# How do I throttle messages from PublicActivity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, public-activity

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include PublicActivity::Model
      tracked owner: :user
```

I'm using the PublicActivity gem to track the "update" action on the Post model. The problem is that if a user clicks on "Update post" 3 times in a minute I get 3 activities for the same "updated post". Is there a way to save an activity only in a range of X-minutes? To prevent flooding.

EDIT:

Maybe a scheduled job to clean up duplicated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
activity = PublicActivity::Activity.where(trackable_id: post.id, owner_id: current_user.id).last
if activity?
  period = Time.zone.now - activity.created_at
  if period > 60              # or any time sec
    @post.create_activity     # your activity creation
  end
else
  @post.create_activity       # your activity creation
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to experiment with disable tracking option. More info [here](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity/wiki/%5BHow-to%5D-Disable-tracking-for-a-class-or-globally/)